# ¿Por qué me aparece este error en c sharp?

Tags: c#, objeto

Me aparece que se ha iniciado un System.NullReferenceException debido a que el objeto de referencia no se ha seleccionado como una instancia del objeto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace JuegoMatrizBinaria
{
  class Program
  {
        public static int[,] matriz = new int [4,4];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] intentosMatriz = new string[2];
            int intentos = 4;
            string intento = string.Empty;

            while (intentos > 0)
            {
                printMatriz(matriz);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Escribe tu jugada(x,y) [Intento #" + intentos + 
"]");
                intento = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                intentosMatriz = intento.Split(',');


                intentos--;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void setMatrizValue(int x,int y)
        {
            if (x<0 || x>3 || y<0 || y > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Jugada Inválida");
                return;
            }

            matriz[x, y] = 1;

            printMatriz(matriz);
        }

        public static void printMatriz(int[,] matriz)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(matriz[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar ocurriendo? Estoy tratando de hacer una matriz. El error me lo da exáctamente en intentosMatriz = intento.Split(','); No se si es porque no he declarado algún tipo de objeto más arriba o cuál puede ser el error. Gracias.

Comment: Al parecer, tu error no es reproducible. Estoy ejecutando tu código [acá](https://onlinegdb.com/jxbZjlnSs) y no parece haber inconvenientes. Por favor, aclara tu problema específico con más detalles. Probablemente posteaste una versión incompleta de tu código ya que `setMatrizValue` nunca es usado.

Comment: El problema está en que a la hora de ejecutar el programa se me para y se queda como algo parecido a un debbuger. El programa se me queda ejecutándose pero no termina de ejecutarse ya que me da error.

Comment: De todas formas puede que el problema sea del compilador y no del código, lo probaré en visual studio code a ver que tal funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Debes escribir en la ejecución, cuando se ejecute el ReadLine lo siguiente:

intento1, intento2, intento3

Y luego saber que hace cada función, porque revisando tu codigo creo que estas un poco enredado con las funciones que estas ocupando o estas ocupandolas no para lo que se han escrito.

Prueba lo que te dije y te funcionará.

Saludos